# Can't get data from useEditController

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I use React Admin and I want to create a custom edit page so I use useEditController to get the data from dataProvider.getOne(). But when I want to restructure the data, it can't do so because of undefined. I think this is because useEditController is an async call and we will have to wait for it before destructuring the data.

This is the code inside my MyEdit.js:

```
const {
basePath,
defaultTitle,
loaded,
loading,
record,
redirect,
resource,
save,
saving,
version,
} = useEditController(props)
const { videoKey } = record
```

When I run this, it said "Cannot destructure property 'videoKey' of 'record' as it is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `useEditController` returns even before the API has responded to the call for the `record`. That means that `record` is undefined until `loaded` is true.

So I advise you to only try and destructure the `record` if the `loaded` value is `true`. Something like:

```
if (!loaded) return null; // or a loading component of your own
const { videoKey } = record;
...
```

Comment: Do you mean that the component will rerender when it get the response from the API ?, if that's the case then why it re-render as no states or props has changed?

Comment: Yes, the component will rerender several times - just like most React components, when state, context or props change.